# Edittext click event focus

Tags: android

I have three Edittext fields ed1,ed2,ed3. When user clicked the ed2 /ed3 I have opened the dialog and get the input from that dialog.For the first click cursor comes to the edittext box and for the next click only I can open the dialog to get the input. I need to show the dialog for the first click.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set the EditText to unFocusable.  That way the first touch registers as a click.

In your XML for the EditText(s) in question add:

```
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a Button instead.. but set its background as default EditText..

Answer (score 1):

That's the way the EditText behaves. They have to be focused first to trigger the `onClick` event.

Edit:
Like Barak points out, you can disable the "focusability" and you can make it open in one click. The drawback is that you won't be able to type on the EditText (which might be fine for your use case).

Comment: Not true...  use `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` in the XML and the first touch on the EditText will register as a click.

Comment: Right, but doesn't that make it not typeable?

Comment: Yes, but if you're clicking it like a button, I don't think you want it to be typeable anyway.  :)  I've used it for date and time entry in forms when I want the user to click on the EditText and pop a picker dialog, and put the results of the picker in the EditText.  Basically I'm doing that to maintain the "look" with the rest of the inputs but enforcing the entry to be the correct form/format (which is what it sounds like the OP is trying to do).

Comment: Yeah, it's a good option if he indeed doesn't want it focusable :D

Answer (score 0):

To keep the `EditText` typable you can do a little trick.

If it is only needed to open the `Dialog` in first time and then use the `EditText` normally you can do this:

```
public class EditTextActivity extends Activity {
    EditText et1;
    int clickCount = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);

         et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_et1);
         et1.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
         setOnClickListeners();


    private void setOnClickListeners(){
         location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            if (clickCount == 0){
                OpenDialog(); //Call the function to open the dialog created by you
                et1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            }
            clickCount = 1;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I put this answer according to the development of this question. @Barak says to define `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`, it's correct but as @dmon says: "The drawback is that you won't be able to type on the EditText". 
I put this to solve the problem.